# Marklogic admin interface read only access

Tags: admin, marklogic

Only Marklogic administrators are able access the Marklogic admin interface. It would be helpful for developers and support personnel to have read-only access to the admin interface to see how various instances are configured. But I didn't see an option to set up read-only users. Is there such an option?

Comment: I have not tested this, but there is an execution privilege called `admin-ui`. You could try creating a new role with that execution privilege and give a user that role.

Comment: Would Configuration Manager suit this need if the user roles were properly defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via the "Configuration Manager" which is available as a tab at the top of port 8000.  As its help docs explain...

> The Configuration Manager allows you to view the configuration
>   settings for MarkLogic Server resources. A resource is a MarkLogic
>   Server object, such as a database, forest, App Server, group or host.
>
> Use the Configuration Manager to:
>
> - Allow non-admin users read-only access to configuration settings for databases, forests, groups, hosts, and App Servers.
> - Easily search for resources and configuration settings.
> - Safely review settings in read-only mode, then jump directly to the resource in the Admin Interface to modify the settings.
>     (Administrative privileges are required to modify settings).
> - Save resource configurations as XML inside a zip folder.
> - Import previously saved resource configurations. Importing a configuration allows you to compare versions and update configuration
>     settings.
> - View data available through the Management REST API.

Comment: Based on documentation I gave access to 'manage-user' role for the user to have read only configuration manager.